# AngularJS to Angular12 Migration (Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppModule: (?))

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration, angular12

im working on a migration from angularJs 1.8.2 to angular 12.

After i reworked the whole compilation from grunt to webpack, im starting now with the real angular migration. First of all to let Angular and AngularJS run at the same time.
I am following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-from-angularjs-to-angular-with-ngupgrade

But i get the Error Message: *Can't resolve all parameters for AppModule: (?)*

I found a bunch of Solutionadvices, but still cant get it to work.

I builded a realy simple Application to try it and demonstrate the Problem.
You can have a look at: https://github.com/Triggsy22/angularJs-angular12-migration/tree/8aead9a69a349089270e34e5e6c60c5f04160fa1
Just call dist/index.html

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a recommended upgrade path - in truth you should just create a new angular project from the ground up and migrate your views that way.

the delta between angular js and angular 12 with typescript is incredibly vast.

there are so many underpinning architecture changes this will leave you with much more work and potentially many errors that its really worth.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I my specific case the error appears cause of a *wrong loader*.
I was using the *babel-loader* with presets *@babel/preset-typescrip* for typescript files. Now Im using the *awesome-typescript-loader*.

If someone else have same Problems, just check: https://github.com/Triggsy22/angularJs-angular12-migration for a working example, of how AngularJS, Angular and Webpack are working together.